# Item Permission based on Nationality

Tags: permissions, libraries, security

I am trying to restrict access to items in a library based on the users nationality. We have contracts that can be viewed by certain nationalities and not by others. I hit a problem if the user has a dual nationality.

My plan was to put each user in an appropriate SharePoint group (restircting who can members) and to add the group to the permission of the item.

Contact 1 = Nationality 1
User 1 - Nationality 1 = Would have access.
User 2 - Nationality 1 + Nationality 2 = Would not have access but does.

Does anyone have any ideas if or how this is possible.

Many thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you only grant permissions in SP so if you would like to have it like this (as I understand your Q)

- User 1 = Nationality 1 - should have access
- User 2 = Nationality 1 + Nationality 2 - should NOT have access

then if you grant permissions to the group Nationality 1 then also User 2 will be granted access (since he is a member of Nationality 1). You have to make combo groups like to make it work according to your requirements.

- Nationality 1
- Nationality 2
- Nationality 1 + Nationality 2
- etc...

Comment: Just a clarification: you cannot deny any permissions at the level of SharePoint groups, only grant.  Denial is only available at the Web Application policy level.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a solid plan.

Alternatively you could define a field on each item to define what nationality the document is for and based on the value on that field restrict access using a workflow or event receiver.